# Create Spark SQL tables from multiple parquet paths

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, databricks

I use databricks. I am trying to create a table as below

```
        target_table_name = 'test_table_1'
        spark.sql("""
          drop table if exists %s
          """ % target_table_name)
        
        spark.sql("""
          create table if not exists {0}
          USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet
          OPTIONS (
          path ("/mnt/sparktables/ds=*/name=xyz/")
          )
          """.format(target_table_name))
```

Even though using "*" gives me flexibility on loading different files (pattern matching) and eventually create a table, I wish to create a table based on two completely different paths (no pattern matching).

path1 = /mnt/sparktables/ds=*/name=xyz/
path2 = /mnt/sparktables/new_path/name=123fo/

Comment: you can load data into df first: `df = spark.read.parquet(path1, path2, path3)`, and then `df.createOrReplaceTempView(target_table_name)`

Comment: df.createOrReplaceTempView(target_table_name): This would only create a temporary table. However, my need is that I would like to update this table every day.

Answer (score 2):

Spark uses Hive metastore to create these permanent tables. These tables are essentially external tables in Hive.

Generally what you are trying is not possible because Hive external table location needs to be unique at the time of creation.

However, you could still achieve the hive table with different location, if you incorporate partitioning strategy on your hive metastore.

In hive metastore you can have partitions which point to different locations.

However there is no off the shelf way to achieve this. Firstly you would need to specify a partition key for your dataset and create a table from the 1st location where the entire data belongs to one partition. Then alter table to add a new partition.

Sample:

```
create external table tableName(<schema>) partitioned by ('name') location '/mnt/sparktables/ds=*/name=xyz/'
```

Then you can add partitions

```
alter table tableName add partition(name='123fo') location '/mnt/sparktables/new_path/name=123fo/'
```

The alternate to this process is create 2 dataframe out of the 2 location , combine them then `saveAsaTable`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```sql
create or replace view 'mytable' as
select * from parquet.`path1`
union all
select * from parquet.`path2`
```

The view understands how to query from both locations. I assume you will not append/overwrite the table as it would lead to more ambiguity.

Answer (score -2):

You can create data frames separately for two or more parquet files and then union them (assuming they have identical schemas)

```
df1.union(df2)
```